# sqlalchemy document

Tags: sqlalchemy

HI i was reading the chapter 8.3.7 -- Oracle API Reference of sqlalchemy0.5.4 official document.
When talking about connection ,there is a parameter called threaded :

threaded - enable multithreaded access to cx_oracle connections. Defaults to True. Note that this is the opposite default of cx_oracle itself.

Not understand the "this is the opposite default of cx_oracle itself".
Does that mean if i chose threaded=True, while the cx_oracle--threaded=False ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument still works the same, the difference is when you don't specify the argument. Plain cx_Oracle has threaded=False by default, but when using SQLAlchemy multithreaded access is turned on by default. You can still override it with threaded=False.